# Delphi load XML

Tags: xml, delphi, pascal

I've been googling for a while,but i could'nt find the right example.

I have local XML with with Node

And I have a form in my project:

Edit1   |   Submit

I want the when user hits Submit childNode to be created in my XML file for categories.
Like:

```
<categories>
<cat1>Name of Cat(Edit1.Text)</cat1>
</categories>
```

EDIT:

I have Project1.XML file in my .exe directory (/Win32/Debug/Project1.XML):

```
<Kategorijos>
</Kategorijos>
```

In my Form there is an input field (Edit1) and a button (Button1)

On button click program should load Project1.XML, find `<Kategorijos>` and add childNode(`<cat1>Edit1.Text</cat1>`) to it, so it would look like this if Edit1 input value would be equal to 'My first category.':

```
<Kategorijos>
   <cat1>My first caregory</cat1> 
</Kategorijos>
```

I use XE3.

Comment: To a vague question a vague answer. By using [`OXML`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20553999/960757), you can write [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/nmy0N1zt).

Comment: Hi TLama, i've created a procedure from your example http://pastebin.com/0nrHdPKs, but i get an error: class Txmldocument not found.

Comment: @user1804119 Edit your question and include the relevant parts of the code. "I have local XML with Node" says nothing. Also give us input, expected output, any errors.

Comment: And if you get a 'class not found' for any component, you put the cursor in it, press Ctrl-F1 and the help will tell you in which unit it is declared. Then put that unit in your Uses clause.

Comment: I've made changes on the main post. It should be clear now.

Comment: Surely you can start from the Delphi xml docs

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some newbies like me will find this solution I finally found useful:

```
procedure Tform1.addCat (kategorija : string);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  data: IXMLNode;
  xmlNode : IXMLNode;
  newCat : IXMLNode;
begin
  Doc := LoadXMLDocument('Project1.XML');
  data := Doc.DocumentElement;
  xmlNode := data.ChildNodes.FindNode('Kategorijos');
  newCat := xmlNode.AddChild('cat1');
  newCat.Text := kategorija;
  Doc.SaveToFile('Project1.XML');
end;
```